# R Programming: 3D array plots

Tags: arrays, r, plot, 3d

I am trying to do up a 3D array plot in R.

I already have an array built up and defined with the corresponding z-values
e.g. `CVHSP500 = array(0,c((nHSP500-N),N))`

So now I am trying to do a 3D array plot with it. I decided to go with `persp3d(CVHSP500,col = "lightblue",)` and have obtained a rather decent plot.

[3D Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8EUF.png)

So there are obviously some issues with this plot.

1) The coordinates are not defined correctly.

Reading up online on the usage of persp3D, and other R programming functions/packages like slice3D, they all require x, y and z to be separate list. 
I don't understand how to match the values of x and y to the respective z, and since persp3D works perfectly without me having to do that, I decided to use persp3D.
But I will need to insert coordinates for it, but I have no idea how to.

2) Any advice how do I color the plots for different ranges of z?
The ones online all seem to have to refer to individual x, y and z lists and some form of advanced modification which I can't really understand. This light blue color looks okay but it would be good for different ranges of z as well though.

Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform a 2D array representing z for each (x,y) into 3 vectors x, y and z, you can do this:

```
CVHSP500 = array(0,c((nHSP500-N),N))

x <- rep(1:(nHSP500-N),N)
y <- rep(1:N,(nHSP500-N))
z <- CVHSP500
dim(z) <- (nHSP500-N)*N
```